# css navigation bar problems with the submenus

Tags: css

I am hoping that someone could help me out with a css problem that has been driving me crazy all day. I know I'm missing something obvious here, I just don't see it. If you can help that would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/taglegacy/HK7Hy/

And here is the css:

```
body
{
    margin: 20;
    padding: 20;
    text-align: center;
    font: 85% arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    color: #444;
}
#container
{
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #FFF;
}
/*---NavigationBar---*/
ul
{
    font-family: Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    background: #9b1b19;
}
ul li
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
li ul
{
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
ul li a
{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #9b1b19;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li a:hover
{
    background: #af1f1c;
}
li:hover ul
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #af1f1c;
}
li:hover li
{
    float: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    background: #af1f1c;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}
li:hover a
{
    background: #af1f1c;
}
    li:hover li a:hover
{
    background: #af1f1c;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<ul>
<li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Menu 2</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="">Submenu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Submenu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">Submenu 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="">Menu 3</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="">Submenu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Submenu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">Submenu 3</a></li>
<li><a href="">Submenu 4</a></li>
<li><a href="">Submenu 6</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="">Menu 4</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="">Submenu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Submenu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">Really Long Submenu 3 Really Long</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly..?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your issue?

Comment: You are using CSS :hover to how the submenu's. But the hover only works on the parent menu. So leaving the parent closes the submenu! I think you need to do some nice teicks with css or use javascript to show the submenu!

Comment: Yeah... what is your problem exactly?  The "really long submenu title?"

Comment: If the problem is the width of the submenus not stretching to accommodate the text, you should remove the width:100% from the ul style.

Comment: @Timo002 whoops, sorry about that. I'm having problems with the submenus not resizing with the text. I would like this to be done automatically so that I don't have to make changes to the css file every time I need to change a menu item.

Comment: @Timo002 I'm able to select the submenu with ff and ie, so not really understanding what you mean by it closing. Works fine on the fiddle to.

Comment: Using my Android touch device closes the submenu directly when clicking on the parrent. Thought that was the issue!

Comment: `:hover` accessibility on touch devices is an issue for though, heh.

Comment: @Timo002 no problem, I understand. For mobile the user will select the top menu and they will still be able to find their way around without any problems, very simple site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "really long" list item is being cut off because your submenu `ul` is set to the width of it's parent `li`. Take out the `width: 100%` and it'll show the enter text.

Move it so that it only applies to the parent `ul` to retain the navbar width:

`#topnav { width: 100% }`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HK7Hy/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I think, a `position:absolute` is needed for the 2nd ul. Play around a bit with `padding-top` and/or `top`. In the example the `padding-top` is equal to height of main menu items.

```
ul#topnav > li > ul {position: absolute; top:0; left:0; padding-top:36px;}
```

should work, good luck!

Comment: thank you for your time. I'll try it out as well, love playing with css to find a new/better way to do things.

Comment: Helions answer is the better one anyway, not just the better one, it's the right one :-)